# What is the time complexity of contains() of a Set view?

Tags: java, time-complexity, runtime

If I have a TreeSet and I use `contains()` on the Set view of `keySet()` is the time complexity O(1)?

```
Map<String, Integer> map1 = new TreeMap<>();
map1.keySet().contains(xyz);
```

I am wondering as for example `contains()` for HashSet and LinkedHashSet is O(1) but for a TreeSet is O(log(N)) but the `keySet()` method is not returning a HashSet, LinkedSet or TreeSet but just a Set view in general thus making me unsure.

I checked [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) but could not find any performance related information.

I have since found this question: [What is a view of a collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902484/what-is-a-view-of-a-collection)
This makes me think the call of `contains()` is then made by the TreeMap and not the Set and would therefore be O(log(N))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map1.keySet().contains(xyz);` is 100% identical to calling `map1.containsKey(xyz);`. You can verify it by looking at the [source](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/TreeMap.java):

```
public class TreeMap<K,V>
    extends AbstractMap<K,V>
    implements NavigableMap<K,V>, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
{
    // […]

    public Set<K> keySet() {
        return navigableKeySet();
    }

    /**
     * @since 1.6
     */
    public NavigableSet<K> navigableKeySet() {
        KeySet<K> nks = navigableKeySet;
        return (nks != null) ? nks : (navigableKeySet = new KeySet<>(this));
    }

    // […]

    static final class KeySet<E> extends AbstractSet<E> implements NavigableSet<E> {
        private final NavigableMap<E, ?> m;
        KeySet(NavigableMap<E,?> map) { m = map; }

        // […]

        public boolean contains(Object o) { return m.containsKey(o); } // [<-- delegates back to map]

        // […]
    }

    // ...
}
```

=> The key set has the same runtime characteristics as the collection itself. In case of a TreeMap that's O(log(n)) for the contains operation.

Comment: This (or slight adoptions of this) should be true for any view onto any of the standard collections: They tend to be implemented in the most efficient way. I.e. if there's a simple mapping to the original collections methods, then you can safely assume that's what's being done.